# Ubuntu 16.04 sapi package not found

Tags: apt, package-management, tpm

```
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Package expected to install: libsapi

Result: Unable to locate package libsapi
```

Hi, I am trying to install System API (SAPI) package on Ubuntu 16.04

According to [tpm-2.0-tools](https://github.com/01org/tpm2.0-tools/blob/master/INSTALL), in order to build these tools, I need to install this package.

I have been searching around and found out that libsapi is probably the one I am looking for.

However, when I type the following command, it did not give the expected response.

```
sudo apt-get install libsapi
```

Where can I find the package or how can I install it?

Thanks

---

My work-around to do this:

git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/tpm2-tss.git

./bootstrap

./configure

make

make install

If you run this successfully, then you should probably have sapi available now. Switch to the tpm2.0-tools and try again. The error message should go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [libsapi-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libsapi-utils) ([libsapi-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libsapi-dev)) and is in Universe but there is only a version for Zesty (17.04).

You could download the source packages from the links and use [gdebi](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/) to install it.

---

Think I found it: [libtss2-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtss2-utils) (and [libtss2-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libtss2-dev)):

> xenial (16.04LTS) (utils): TPM2 Software stack library - TSS utilities [universe] 0.98+20160226.d4f23cc-0ubuntu2: amd64 arm64 armhf i386 powerpc ppc64el s390x

So ...

```
sudo apt-get install libtss2-utils
sudo apt-get install libtss2-dev
```

---

edit: These 2 seem to be built from `tpm2-tss` (got there from this [bugreport](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815846)).  So next attempt:

```
 sudo apt-get install tpm2-tss
```

Comment: When I run configure provided by tpm-tools 2.0, I still got the following error. The packages have been installed.

Comment: configure: error: Package requirements (sapi) were not met:

No package 'sapi' found

Comment: according to this https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=815846 (mentions " System API (SAPI)) there is also http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/tpm2-tss can you install that one too?

Comment: the same, E: Unable to locate package tpm2-tss

Comment: do you have universe enabled? Those packages should be there.

Comment: btw, how can I install source package through gdebi? I've downloaded it. Thanks

Comment: `sudo gdebi {package}.deb`

Answer (score 1):

In Zesty (17.04)

`sudo apt-get install libsapi-dev`

Comment: Unable to locate package libsapi-dev, is there anything I might be wrong?

Comment: @Rinzwind  answer suggests that this package is available only for Zesty(Ubuntu 17.04). Try his solution.

Comment: [Here](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/pm/tpm2-tss) tpm2-tss for xenial seems to be deleted if you were trying that.